# React-native-flash-message getting under the Card

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper, react-native-flash-message

I am using react-native-flash-message https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flash-message.

Everything works fine as it is easy to use them. But the problem is when i used it with the `Card` component (from react-native-paper), the message hides under the card. I want the message to be on the top of everything.

I tried `zIndex` But it doesnot work.

Here is the demo code;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Avatar, Button, Card, Title, Paragraph } from 'react-native-paper';
import FlashMessage from 'react-native-flash-message';
import { showMessage } from 'react-native-flash-message';

const LeftContent = (props) => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />;
const show = () => {
  showMessage({
    message: 'This is a message',
  });
};

const MyComponent = () => (
  <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 30}}>
    <Card style={{ margin: 30 }} elevation={30}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 30}}>
        <Card.Title
          title="Card Title"
          subtitle="Card Subtitle"
          left={LeftContent}
        />
        <Card.Content>
          <Title>Card title</Title>
          <Paragraph>Card content</Paragraph>
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Cover source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/700' }} />
        <Card.Actions>
          <Button onPress={() => show()}>show message</Button>
        </Card.Actions>
      </ScrollView>
    </Card>
    <FlashMessage style={{ marginTop: 20 }} position="top" />
  </View>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

Note that this problem only occurs on android devices. On ios, it works fine.

Though i found a solution. Putting `<FlashMessage style={{ marginTop: 20 }} position="top" />` inside the card component will resolve it, but i have enabled `FlashMessage` globally, so i want to change it globally and don't want to put it in every card component

Comment: Please paste your code so that we can take look on it.

Comment: @DipanSharma edited my question. Please have a look

Comment: Actually the answer which i mentioned in the question is the only possible way to  do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some search, i found that though the `react-native-flash-message` is not made in that way to be rendered on top of everything like `card`, `modals` or `dialog`.

So one way to solve it (infact, i think this is the only way) would be to wrap the `FlashMessage` component in `card` and give it some high elevation (say 1000). Note that the elevation provided to it should by the largest among all cards used.

Comment: Could you just set the style values for elevation and zIndex on the FlashMessage component itself? I.E. <FlashMessage style={{ elevation: 1000, zIndex: 1000 }} />

Comment: Tried that also. This doesn't work. My answer is probably the only way to do so, Card component from react-natve-paper is rendered on  top of everything. So we cannot overcome this except by setting elevation of the card zero.